# Unable to fire ng-blur event from ag-grid input box cell renderer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I have the following cell rendering for `ag-grid`, with this the input box is appearing correctly with its desired model value. The problem is coming with `ng-blur` event. The alert box inside the `ng-blur` function is never firing up. Can any one guide me to fix this? I have even used `$timeout` but still the event is not firing up.

```
  return function(params) {
      params.$scope.assOvHrs= params.value;
      params.$scope.computeStatus = function() {
          $timeout(function() {
              alert(" blur is fired ");
          }, 0);
      };
      return '<span ><input type="text" ng-blur="computeStatus()"  ng-model="assOvHrs"> </span>'
  }
```

Comment: where is this compiled into the HTML?  you can't just store angular markup in a variable, append it into the DOM, and expect angular to know that it's there......  I would doubt the `ng-model` working as well.

Comment: I have cellRenderer  as getCellRendererMapping(eachHeaderColumn), the above code is inside this getCellRendererMapping function based on conditions validation if succeed then I am returning the above. Through my grid options I am already compiling it, angularCompileRows: true,    angularCompileHeaders: true. So I feel compilation is of not a concern, Otherwise I guess I don't even get the input box displayed with its model value but  I am getting input box with its model value correctly, only ng-blur is not firing up.

Comment: I use the tempModel to bind with `<input>` and handle the focusout/blur/onmodelchange of the input with the ag-grid framework getValue(). Please, see the method definition [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/).